# C++/CLI: Queue of member function pointers

Tags: function, pointers, c++-cli, queue, member

I want to use a queue to synchronize access to a serial port that is being shared between several independant blocks of code.
Every block provides a callback function which, when needed, will be enqueued and takes care of exactly one atomic operation on the serial port.
A timer then periodically executes all pending operations, hopefully with no interferance.

Since I am relatively new to C++/CLI programming, I was able to create a *System::Collections::Queue* and enqueued some strings; but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to do the same with pointers to my callback functions (*void Test()*).

I googled intensively, but even the most simple examples did not work for me. All this delegate, Boost, Marshal, gcnew stuff is confusing me a bit right now.

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express.
Hope you can help!

Regards from Germany,

Paul

Comment: I usually avoid using delegates and fancy callbacks myself and stick to callback by inheritance, because it makes more sense to me. If you need to traverse the managed/unmanaged layer, then its not too hard to write a wrapper in C++/CLI that will act as an intermediate callback layer which will pass the call up to the managed environment. At least I think its easier than learning about marshalling delegates to functors and such.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET/CLR world the System.Delegate class is an analogue of the function pointer.

Since you are doing some low-level stuff and the callbacks are written in high-level managed environment, the need for marshaling arises.

To use managed function pointers as native callbacks you need this MSDN article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer(v=vs.80).aspx

If you have a queue of System.Delegate instances, then just do the D.DynamicInvoke() call with a list of appropriate arguments.

Comment: I _think_ you misunderstood me: I have no problems accessing the serial port whatsoever, as _System::IO::Ports::SerialPort_ works fine for me. All I want to do really is getting said function into and later on out of my queue (and execute it, of course). The queue, timer and callback functions are actually all in the same class. There are no restrictions on the callback function, it might aswell be managed or not. (Thus, my example function name was _void Test()_, it might aswell be _System::Void Test()_. But wait, does that even make the difference between managed and unmanaged code?)

Comment: So you have an event on which you want to "store" the function call on queue and then, on another event, you want to "pop" the function call from queue and execute it ? I understand that the Serial Port you mentioned is irrelevant, but the conversion of unmanaged function pointers to .NET delegates requires some work.

Comment: Then what is the problem for you (put aside unfamiliarity with .NET) to declare the struct with a System.Delegate and object[] fields which represent the call and then use the list of such calls ?